# How to make a segue to second item of tab bar?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder, sequence

I have a strange trouble with making of segue to second item of tab bar from second button. I have `MainViewController` with 2 buttons. First button must be linked with first item of tab bar and second button must be linked with second item of tab bar.

The task looks easy. Making segue for first is elementary (I just linked first button first Tab Bar Controller) but I have a trouble with linking of second button. If I link second button with second View I will see view controller without tab bar. What Do I need to do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use prepare for "segue" to pass to the tabView the next view.

1) Create a CustomTabViewController and load in your tabView.
[image]

2) select the action from the ViewController to the CustomTabBarViewConstroller. 
[image]

4) Instantiate the buttons in your ViewController and user the sender delegate to select the view to display.

5) Here is the code that you need.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Create a value for chosed view
private var nextViewNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "tabBar" {

        let nextView = segue.destination as! CustomTabBarViewController

        switch (nextViewNumber) {
        case 1:
            nextView.selectedIndex = 0

        case 2:
            nextView.selectedIndex = 1

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func FistView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.nextViewNumber = 1
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tabBar", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func SecontView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.nextViewNumber = 2
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tabBar", sender: self)

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Would anyone be able to explain how to adapt the above to pass over a `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row` as part of the segue so I could trigger the tab from a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

In the view you are coming from:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as! TabBarViewController
    vc.nextViewNumber = 4 // 4 is the tabbar number, tabbars start from 0.
}
```

Then, in your `TabBarViewController` - Imagining you already have a tabbar you want to get to most often.

```
var nextViewNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.selectedIndex = 2

    if nextViewNumber == 4 {
        self.selectedIndex = 4 // Selects the 5th tabbar
        nextViewNumber = 2 // Resets
    }

}
```