# How do I pass indexPathForSelectedRow into a UITabView via a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to segue from a `UITableView` to a specific tab within a `UITabBarController`. While googling, I found two sets of info that seem to indicate how to do, but neither were using a `UITableView` as the source.

The first source is this wonderfully written answer I found here on StackOverflow: [How to make a segue to second item of tab bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738649/how-to-make-a-segue-to-second-item-of-tab-bar)

The second source was this site: http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/

I have been attempting to combine the two for my app. Below is a truncated version of my originating UIViewController (I can post the full one if needed, just most the code isn't related to this segue, I don't think):

```
class BonusListViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Table View Configuration
        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if isFiltering() {
                print("Showing \(filteredBonuses.count) Filtered Results")
                return filteredBonuses.count
            }

            print("Found \(bonuses.count) rows in section.")
            return bonuses.count
        }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
    }

    private var nextViewNumber = Int()

    @IBAction func secondView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.nextViewNumber = 2
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tabBar", sender: self)
    }   

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if segue.identifier == "tabBar" {

                let destination = segue.destination as! TabBarViewController

                switch (nextViewNumber) {
                case 1:
                    destination.selectedIndex = 0

                case 2:
                    destination.selectedIndex = 1
                    if self.isFiltering() {
                        destination.bonus = filteredBonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
                    } else {
                        destination.bonus = bonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
                    }

                default:
                    break
                }
            }
      }
}
```

My issue resolves around trying to pass the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row` over to the `UITabViewController`. In the `prepare(for segue)` near the end of the above code snippet I'm getting a compile error for the `destination.bonus =` lines that says,

> Value of type 'TabBarViewController' has no member 'bonus'

This is technically true as I'm just trying to pass through the TabBarViewController to the second tab it controls.

How can I fix the above to let me tap on a cell, and then pass the selected row over to the target `UITabView`?

EDIT: In case it helps, here is a picture of the storyboard.
[image: App Storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

> Value of type 'TabBarViewController' has no member 'bonus'
>   Because  'TabBarViewController' has no property named bonus

You can subclass  `TabBarViewController`  add property `bonus`

and set it from segue like

```
guard let destination = segue.destination as? YourTabbarSubClass else {return }
```

and you can access `bonus` by  `destination.bonus`

Now when you need that  `bonus` from tabbar controllers you can use it with `(self.tabbarController as! YourTabbarSubClass).bonus`

**EDIT**

```
class  TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
   // Add property bonus here
     var bouns:BounsStruct?

}
```

Now From your view controller where you need that

```
class YourFirstTabVC:UIVIewController {
   //where you need that 
   self.bouns = (self.tabbarController as!  TabBarViewController).bouns
   self.tableview.reloadData()


}
```

Comment: I somewhat follow what you are suggesting. Any chance you could clarify it a bit more though? `bonus` points at `JsonFile.JsonBonuses`, which is contained in a separate JsonFile.swift file. So I think you are saying to add it to the UITabBarController's swift file to get rid of the error, then within that file do another `prepare(for segue)` that then points to the tab I'm aiming for (which is the second tab)?

Comment: @DJFriar No. You Just have to create new class. as subclass of TabbarController. Now assign that to tabbar controller in  storyboard. Now All view controller that is part of the the tabbar controller (2 - 3 what number of tab you have) can access that property with self.tabbarcontroller. No need segue there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have my Tab Bar View Controller pointed at TabBarViewController.swift. Within that, it is currently blank. I think you are suggesting to add a class of `bonus` in there, but I'm not sure what I should put. The only way I've defined `bonus` in any other of my pages is something like `var bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses?`, which references JsonFile.swift, which contains just the struct of the JSON I'm using to populate the UITableView.

Comment: @DJFriar Yes you have to take bonus variable there in tabbar controller class

Comment: So I have done the change to TabBarViewController and added `var bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses?` to it. In my CaptureBonusTabBar, I get an error when I try to add `self.bonus = (self.TabBarViewController as! TabBarViewController.bonus)`. If I add it to the top of the class, then I get "Expected Declaration in declaration of 'CaptureBonusTabViewController'." That declaration looks like, `class CaptureBonusTabViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {`

Comment: If I move the `self.bonus = (self.TabBarViewController as! TabBarViewController.bonus)` into my `viewDidLoad`, then I get an error that states "Var 'bonus' is not a member type of 'TabBarViewController'". This file originally had `var bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses?` at the top of the class, but leaving it or removing it doesn't affect the errors I'm getting. However, removing it does make every instance of `bonus.` show an "unresolved identifier" error as well.